# Show some of the rows in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have a Google Sheet stores all training records of all students. I want to set up something to let the clients only see their own records. If it is something Google Sheet could help me?

Please see below an example of the Google Sheet (database ). Thank you so much

```
Name    Unit    Completion Date

John    AAA    22/11
Sarah   AAA    22/11
Tim     AAA    1/11
Steve   AAA    31/10
Ben     AAA    30/10
Sarah   BBB    20/9
Tim     BBB    4/10
Steve   BBB    19/11
Ben     BBB    20/11
John    CCC    3/5
Sarah   CCC    10/10
Tim     CCC    5/9
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually based on the number of records you have.

You can use the Publish to web function or use importrange function.

So in our case, if the number is between 10~20 it's doable and won't be that exhausting.

If it's more than that, since you will have to create a separate spreadsheet/published links for each of the 30 students.

Here's the importrange function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en
And here's how you can publish the Sheet https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0

If you're going to use the publish to web function, you will have to create a separate subsheet for each student too.

I know it is not the ultimate solution, but it's a workaround.

Another solution you could do is to use Appscript to send this data directly to their E-Mails with their own records.